# Cannot connect to DeepStream Node.js server if using any custom plugins

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, deepstream.io

So, if I use my DeepStream server as the following

```
const {Deepstream} = require('@deepstream/server')

const server = new Deepstream({

server.start()
```

it's working just fine I can connect to it from my frontend app like the following

```
const {DeepstreamClient} = require('@deepstream/client')
const client = new DeepstreamClient('192.168.88.238:6020')
client.login()
```

but If I add MongoDB storage instance or RethinkDB
[NPM - RethinkDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@deepstream/storage-rethinkdb)

```
const {Deepstream} = require('@deepstream/server')

const server = new Deepstream({
    storage: {
        name: 'rethinkdb',
        options: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 28015
        }
    }
})

// start the server
server.start()
```

I get the following error message when trying to reach my ds server.
(I've also tried to connect via WSS:// instead of WS://)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So hi everybody who has the same problem as me...
I figured it out!
So first of all what the npm packages documentation says from the usage of the [Mongo DB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@deepstream/storage-mongodb) driver is completely out of data

so what they say how should u use the npm package :

```
var Deepstream = require( 'deepstream.io' ),
    MongoDBStorageConnector = require( 'deepstream.io-storage-mongodb' ),
    server = new Deepstream();
 
server.set( 'storage', new MongoDBStorageConnector( {
  connectionString: 'mongodb://test:test@paulo.mongohq.com:10087/munchkin-dev',
  splitChar: '/'
}));
 
server.start();
```

INSTEAD OF ALL THIS!

You ain't really need the `'deep stream.io-storage-MongoDB'` because it's an old module (based on: [image]), and u don't really need to use this way...

The correct usage of the MongoDB connector :

```
const {Deepstream} = require('@deepstream/server');
const server = new Deepstream({
    storage: {
        name: "mongodb",
        options: {
            connectionString: MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING ,
            splitChar: '/'
        }
    }
});

server.start();
```

or you can also create a config. yaml file from all this :

```
storage:
  name: mongodb
  options:
    connectionString: 'MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING'
    # optional database name, defaults to `deepstream`
    database: 'DATABASE_NAME'
    # optional table name for records without a splitChar
    # defaults to deepstream_docs
    defaultCollection: 'COLLECTION_NAME'

    # optional character that's used as part of the
    # record names to split it into a table and an id part
    splitChar: '/'
```

and pass it to the deep stream constructor as below:

```
const {Deepstream} = require('@deepstream/server');
const server = new Deepstream('config.yaml');

server.start();
```

Comment: I will post how to use the rethink connector too